# How do I return the last element in an array that completes a specific condition in java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

For example, if there is the given array of {50, 33, 60, 40, 20}, find the average of this array, and then return the number that is greater than the average (in this case, 40, 50 and 60). If there are more than one, return the last greatest number in the array(in this case, 40). I'm trying to do this using a for loop and if statements.

Comment: This seems like a straightforward task involving a few loops. What have you tried so far? Which part did you get stuck on?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement.  40 is not greater than the average value from this array.

Comment: @sorifiend I tried using and/or operations on the if statements, but it just gets the first element that completes the condition, I guess I have to find a way to iterate all the way to the end of the array, which is where I'm stuck on

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code. Then people may be able to help you with it. After all, you are asking for help with the code you have already written, correct?

Comment: Without code this question will end up being closed. But here's what I would do: 1. Write a function that will take an array as input and calculate the average value, returning that average to the caller. 2. Write code that will look at each value in the array, comparing it against the average that your helper function calculated. 3. If the value is equal-or-greater than the average, do your extra checks to pick the winner (not clear from your example.. "last greatest number" sounds like "60" should be returned, but you said "40") – anyway, whatever this behavior, write a function for that.

Comment: Is "last" a typo, should it be "least" here "return the least greatest number" (the next number after the average) or "return the last greatest number" (the largest number)?

Comment: Oh I took it that "greatest" was a typo for "greater"; and "last" meant in the order they appear in the array.  That would give 60 as the answer, because 40 is not greater than 40.6.

Comment: @sorifiend The title suggests it's not a typo.

Comment: This is how I interpret the criteria: "Given an array of numbers `N`, and an average of those numbers `a`, then find the number `x ∈ N : x > a`. If there is more than one such number `x`, then return the `x` at the greatest index `i` of `N`." Is that a correct interpretation? If so, your example output of `40` does not make sense and the actual output should be `60` (the average of `[50, 33, 60, 40, 20]` is `40.6`, making only `50` and `60` greater than the average, and `60` appears after `50` in the array).

Comment: And given that interpretation, the "naive" algorithm is to loop over the array once to compute the average, then loop over the array a second time while keeping track of the latest number greater than the average that you've come across. It will be an O(n²) algorithm. Not sure if a better algorithm exists.

Comment: @Slaw You can do the second iteration backwards through the array, and stop as soon as you come to a greater-than-average number.  And I believe both that it's O(n), not O(n²),  and that there's no algorithm that's better than O(n).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Oh duh. Not sure why I missed the loop-backwards-and-break-early optimization. And oops, you're right, both algorithms (forward and backward) would be O(n).

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding average of values of the array is

```
(50+33+60+40+20)/5 = 40.6
```

So using Java 8, we can do it as below:

```
int [] arr = {50, 33, 60, 40, 20};
int average = Arrays.stream(arr).sum()/arr.length;
```

And as there are more numbers greater than 40 in the array you need to filter all those elements which are greater than or equals to average (40) and and sort it and return first element if present or else return -1

```
int smallestValue = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(i -> i >= average).sorted().findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

Comment: How does `.sorted().findFirst()` fulfill OP's requirements? I'm not sure if "last greatest" means last or greatest, but this is neither.

Comment: @shmosel sorted will return filtered elements as 40, 50, 60 and findFirst will return the first element

Comment: I know, but that's not what was requested.

Comment: Well, I guess OP does say the result should be 40, so who knows.

Comment: he said answer should be 40

Comment: @shmosel the last greater than the average of the numbers

Comment: @user19318020 I still don't understand. If you mean the greatest number, wouldn't that be 60?

Comment: Yes, whereas OP clearly made a mistake identifying 40 as the answer, it seems clear to me that they meant the last number, in the order of the original array, that's greater than the average.

Comment: Got it. So this is still wrong, because it returns the lowest above-average number, not the last in the array.

Comment: Maybe change `.sorted().findFirst()` to `.reduce((a, b) -> b)`.

Comment: The other error is that they've used integer division, then done `>=`.  Once you change the `>=` to `>`, the integer division no longer matters.

Comment: Based on OP's comments about 40 it looks like they want the "least" greatest number (the next number before the average), but we need clarification

Comment: I suspect OP wants the last number in the array that's greater or equal to the average rounded down. If only there were someone we could ask...

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of being able to comment under a question, was that one should ask under the question what it means, until the OP makes the question sufficiently clear;  and only then should one answer.  As opposed to providing an answer that may or may not match what the OP actually wants.  But I guess everyone has their own way of working.

Comment: And I also find "greater than or equal to average rounded down" to be a very bizarre criterion.

Comment: Which makes it consistent with the rest of the post.